# can any one tell me how to reduce the bitbucket repo size

Tags: bitbucket, git-rewrite-history

git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch logs' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

rm -rf .git/refs/original

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

git gc --prune=now

git gc --aggressive --prune=now

git push origin --force --all

These are the commends i used to reduce bitbucket repo size but the size was increasd

Comment: I imagine you ran those commands on your local repository? AFAIK, `git gc` does not propagate to remotes.

Answer (score 1):

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570961/6309):

- `git gc` will be run regularly by BitBucket
- you can force Bitbucket to perform a `git gc`

See also "[Reduce repository size](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html)"