# How clean git repository with commit which not in work tree

Tags: git, bitbucket, bfg-repo-cleaner

I cleaned the Git repository (Bitbucket cloud) with bfg, but the last commit remained uncleaned (as written in the bfg documentation: By default the BFG doesn't modify the contents of your latest commit on your master (or 'HEAD') branch, even though it will clean all the commits before it.).

However, I didn’t see it and wanted to run `git gc` in a Bitbucket.
For this I did "`git reset --hard HEAD`" and rolled back to it then "`git push --force`".
But repository size increased?!

Now I have this commit with the old history left in the repository, and bfg cannot clean it, what should I do?
How can I remove it, since it is no longer attached to the working tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote in bitbucket support, they ran the script "git gc" on server and the old story was cleaned

Comment: You should be able to trigger a `git gc` on BitBucket side (without having to contact them). See [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570961/6309).

Comment: I know, I did it, it didn’t help me

Comment: Bitbucket support could have some answers about why their own process did not trigger a `git gc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell BFG to change the last commit too with the `--no-blob-protection` flag. *(This is from the BFG-Repo-Cleander documentation).

Alternatively, you can create a new commit that removes the bad file and then run BFG normally.

Comment: I tried to do so, but the commit is no longer in the working tree and the bfg does not see it

Answer (score 0):

Try again, this time using [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [will replace BFG and git filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)

As mentioned in its documentation:

> [there is] an extra steps to delete the other tags and do another gc are still required to clean out the old objects and avoid mixing new and old history before pushing somewhere

`git filter-repo` does avoid confusing users (and prevent accidental re-pushing of old stuff) due to mixing old repo and rewritten repo together.

---

Note: on the *server* side (ie, where you are pushing to), a git gc needs to be run, which is done regularly but not immediately.
That is the [case for GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364721/6309), as well as BitBucket.

See Atlassian documentation "[How to perform a manual garbage collection on a repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-perform-a-manual-garbage-collection-on-a-repository-867194296.html)"

> Bitbucket implements its own garbage collection logic without relying on `git gc` anymore (this is achieved by setting the [gc] auto = 0 on all repositories).
>   When a fork is created, the pruneexpire=never is added to the git configuration and this is removed when the last fork is deleted.

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253227/6309):

> BitBucket will run `git gc` themselves in response to doing `git reset --hard HEAD~1` (which discards last commit) followed by `git push -f`.

So in your case:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "empty commit"
git push

git reflog expire --expire-unreachable="30m" --all
git prune --expire="30m" -v
git gc --prune="30m"
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push -f
```

And a `git gc` should be done on BitBucket side!